# Multi-monitor Xorg nVidia on Ubuntu 10.10 without root?

Tags: xorg, twinview, nvidia, multi-monitor

Here at work we just set up a Ubuntu Terminal Server, All of our workstations have multiple monitors, of different sizes, 2-3 screens and varying nVidia video card models, but they all are nvidia. I at least have been using Twin-View. But I don't want to have to log in every day and set up Twin-View with `nvidia-settings` first thing. Is there a way to set up Twin-View from a configuration file? or possibly a startup script? I don't have root access to the TS, however if we could find a one size fits all `xorg.conf` configuration that makes multi-monitor just work on every machine then I might be able to convince the TS admin.

Comment: eventually something got added to gdm stuff... but idk what.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the “*Loading Settings Automatically*” section of [the nvidia-settings(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nvidia-settings) you can save the `nvidia-settings` configuration to a user config file and then call nvidia-settings to load it automatically from your `.xinitrc`, `.xsession`, or whatever your desktop session startup uses.

Comment: ok but how do I get twin view set in `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` in the first place?

Comment: Configure TwinView in the nvidia-settings gui as normal, then choose the last item in the left column, *nvidia-settings Configuration*, and on that tab click the *Save Current Configuration* button to create ~/.nvidia-settings-rc

Comment: tried that. doesn't work... pretty sure it either doesn't load the configuration settings right, or doesn't save them right. `grep -i twin ~/.nvidia-settings-rc` show's nothing